# Expectation of product of matrices

Tags: matrices, expectation, random

Let $H$ be a random matrix, and $x$ be a random vector with $E[xx^{H}]=R$. 
They are independent.

I want to calculate $E[Hxx^{H}H^{H}]$, where $A^{H}$ is a Hermitian of $A$.

Does the equation $E[Hxx^{H}H^{H}]=E[HRH^{H}]$ hold?

Comment: How do you define raising the vector $x$ by the matrix $H$, i.e. what does $x^H$ mean?

Comment: Presumably $x^H$ means the conjugate transpose of $x$ and this "H" is not to be confused with the random matrix $H$. If this is the case, please either use another symbol to denote the random matrix, or change $x^H$ to $x^\ast$ to avoid confusion.